# Python ошибка в синтаксисе по не понятной причине

Tags: python

```
nums = {1, 2, 3, 4.}

print(nums)

nums = [1, True, 3.4, Дурень.]
nums*[*0] = 70
```

Когда активирую этот код высвечиваеться ошибка в синтаксисе и указывает на квадратную скобку которую я пометил сверху звездочками.

Comment: Если ответ помог вам, отметьте его как принятый. Для этого нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 1):

`Дурень` должно быть в кавычках, если вы хотите хранить строку. Так же строка `nums[0] = 70` должна быть на новой строчке, если у вас это не так

Comment: Большое спасибо Бро.